# Add Text at Cursor and Set Headings using Google Apps Script in Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to insert specific text at my cursor to a Google Doc via a custom menu created via Google Apps Script. I am then trying to format that text to specific headings, body, etc. The below code is not working and is inserting all text with the same format as the surrounding text within the Google Doc. I have tried a number of different methods to accomplish this but am hoping for some help or tips!

[Custom Google Doc Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv7XY.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gogca.png)

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taZlk.png)

```js
function menuItem12() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
 
  var headerAttr = {}
  headerAttr[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2;

  var bodyAttr = {}
  bodyAttr[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL;
  
  var text = cursor.insertText("Resource Link");
  text.setLinkUrl("https://www.google.com");

  var header = cursor.insertText("Resource Heading\n");
  header.editAsText().setAttributes(0, header.getText().length, headerAttr);


  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Resources added.');
  
  }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `Trying to insert specific text at my cursor to a Google Doc via a custom menu created via Google Apps Script. I am then trying to format that text to specific headings, body, etc.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for the reply. For context, the custom menu I built holds the names of specific resources (e.g. links), and clicking an option in the custom menu would insert that link wherever my cursor is in my Google Doc. Some of these resources contain multiple sets of links, so I am trying to format these with corresponding Headers to organize the content. I have added photos to my post to help clarify as well - hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Where can I confirm the situation for achieving your "Expected Result"?